# Get matched range item from array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array which is named as tiers and one quantity variable. Now I am trying to get the matched range value from my tier array. Based on the matched result I want to calculate the discount. I tried to with find method but it gives me an unexpected ouput.

**Actual output**
`{id: 1, discount_percent:0, quantity:6, title:"Tier 1"}`

**Expeceted Output**
`{id: 3, discount_percent:10, quantity:10, title:"Tier 3"}`

```
let tiers = [
   {id: 1, discount_percent:0, quantity:6, title:"Tier 1"},
   {id: 2, discount_percent:5, quantity:8, title:"Tier 2"},
   {id: 3, discount_percent:10, quantity:10, title:"Tier 3"},
   {id: 4, discount_percent:12, quantity:12, title:"Tier 4"},
   {id: 5, discount_percent:14, quantity:14, title:"Tier 5"},
   {id: 6, discount_percent:20, quantity:16, title:"Tier 6"},
   {id: 7, discount_percent:40, quantity:18, title:"Tier 7"},
   {id: 8, discount_percent:50, quantity:50, title:"Tier 8"},
]
```

```
function calculateDiscount(){
   const ordersQuanity = 10;
   const tier = tiers.find((_tier) => _tier.quantity <= ordersQuanity);
   ...
}
```

Comment: `_tier.quantity <= ordersQuanity` this should be `_tier.quantity >= ordersQuanity` You need to find the first object where quantity is  greater than or equal to given threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generic situation of a number of objects with `discount_percent`s and `quantity`s, `.find` isn't the right approach because it'll stop as soon as it finds a match. Consider `.reduce` instead - if an element being iterated over passes the test *and* it has a greater `discount_percent` than the current element in the accumulator (if there's anything in the accumulator to begin with), return it instead.

```js
let tiers = [
   {id: 1, discount_percent:0, quantity:6, title:"Tier 1"},
   {id: 2, discount_percent:5, quantity:8, title:"Tier 2"},
   {id: 3, discount_percent:10, quantity:10, title:"Tier 3"},
   {id: 4, discount_percent:12, quantity:12, title:"Tier 4"},
]
function calculateDiscount(){
   const ordersQuanity = 10;
   const bestTier = tiers.reduce((a, tier) => (
     tier.quantity <= ordersQuanity && (!a || tier.discount_percent > a.discount_percent)
       ? tier
       : a
   ), null) || tiers[0]; // alternate with the first element of the array
   // if you want to default to that tier even if the quantity isn't sufficient
   console.log(bestTier);
}
calculateDiscount();
```

If you happen to be able to assume that every increased `discount_percent` comes with a larger quantity, and the array is sorted, you can use `.find` if you reverse the array first (so that the items with the greatest `discount_percent` are iterated over first).

```js
let tiers = [
   {id: 1, discount_percent:0, quantity:6, title:"Tier 1"},
   {id: 2, discount_percent:5, quantity:8, title:"Tier 2"},
   {id: 3, discount_percent:10, quantity:10, title:"Tier 3"},
   {id: 4, discount_percent:12, quantity:12, title:"Tier 4"},
];
const tiersReversed = [...tiers].reverse();
function calculateDiscount(){
   const ordersQuanity = 10;
   const tier = tiersReversed
     .find((_tier) => _tier.quantity <= ordersQuanity)
      || tiers[0]; // alternate with the first element of the array
   // if you want to default to that tier even if the quantity isn't sufficient
   console.log(tier);
}
calculateDiscount();
```

The snippet works just as well for the dataset in the edited question.

```js
let tiers = [
   {id: 1, discount_percent:0, quantity:6, title:"Tier 1"},
   {id: 2, discount_percent:5, quantity:8, title:"Tier 2"},
   {id: 3, discount_percent:10, quantity:10, title:"Tier 3"},
   {id: 4, discount_percent:12, quantity:12, title:"Tier 4"},
   {id: 5, discount_percent:14, quantity:14, title:"Tier 5"},
   {id: 6, discount_percent:20, quantity:16, title:"Tier 6"},
   {id: 7, discount_percent:40, quantity:18, title:"Tier 7"},
   {id: 8, discount_percent:50, quantity:50, title:"Tier 8"},
]
function calculateDiscount(ordersQuanity){
   const bestTier = tiers.reduce((a, tier) => (
     tier.quantity <= ordersQuanity && (!a || tier.discount_percent > a.discount_percent)
       ? tier
       : a
   ), null) || tiers[0]; // alternate with the first element of the array
   // if you want to default to that tier even if the quantity isn't sufficient
   console.log(bestTier);
}
calculateDiscount(10);
calculateDiscount(20);
```

Comment: both of the approaches are working, but if the quantity is less then any tier quantity then it returns null or undefined. Please check with `const ordersQuanity = 5`. In that case what should I do? please suggest?

Comment: Yes, that's what your data would seem to indicate the expected output would be. If the threshold for the lowest tier is `quantity: 6`, then `quantity: 5` will not pass any thresholds.

Comment: In that case, if does not match any tier I want the first tier to be returned, is there any way I can return the first tier within the `reduce` or `find method`?

Comment: I'd move the condition outside. eg `.reduce(...) || tiers[0]`

Comment: I am reopening the issue because, if the quantity is 20 then the solutions are not working.

Comment: They both look to produce the expected output - see the snippet at the end. `ordersQuanity` of 10 results in ID 3 (quantity threshold 10). `ordersQuanity` of 20 results in ID 7 (quantity threshold 18 - there's no other object with a threshold between 18 and 20, so 18 is the closest available)

Answer (score 0):

`function discountPercent(item){
return item.discount_percent == 10
}

console.log(tiers.find(discountPercent))